# T-SQL Some questions about a recursive query (CTE)

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I take all items (e.g advertisements) from a tree using CTE ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270969/t-sql-how-to-get-all-items-from-a-tree-in-t-sql)), but I'm wondering about two things - the hardest part:

1) is it somehow possible to get all category names of the found advertisements ? (in the recursive CTE query, look at the hyperlink above)

2) And (optional) how to get the total **found** advertisement's count of the each category ? I mean, let's say I found 6 items from 3 categories and I'd like to see the result in that way

```
category1 (6) -\
|               category3 (4)
category2 (2)
```

Any ideas will be so helpful

Comment: The answer includes a link to an article explaining things - have you considered *reading* that link?

Answer (score 1):

for the first question you need to go from down to up, it could be resolved with changing querying order ex:

```
with CTE (id, pid, name) 
as
(
select id, parentid as pid,name
from category
where id = @lowLevelCategory
union all
select CTE.pid as id , category.parentid as pid, category.name
from CTE 
inner join category 
on category.id = CTE.pid
)
select * from ss
```

for the second one: you can calculate only count of sub items, but not  summ and you need some function for this calculations, because grouping or subselecting can't be in recursive part